# Query Selected Items using checkbox in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, checkbox

I like to ask if how would it be possible that the selected items in the checkbox will be used in making linq query in MVC.
I have this one in my view where in I displayed all the possible options in which the user will just simply select the types of softwares that will be used to generate reports.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create_Report", "Softwares",
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = "target2"
            })) 
        { 
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
             <p>For A Reports: Kindly check softwares to create reports.</p><br />
            foreach (var item in Model) { 
                <input type="checkbox" value="@item.software_name" name="software_type"/>@item.software_name
                <br />
            }


            <input type="submit" value="Create Report"/>

        }
```

After that, I want that the selected software types will be used in the query like for example if the user selects Adobe Pro, Adobe Illustrator, MS Visio, and Acrobat, the query should go like "Select from Software _table where software__type = "Adobe Pro" && software_type ="Adobe Illustrator && "so fort.

Is there any ways to shorten the query using the selected items from the checkbox? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You are getting the selected items posted, right? Just show the controller action then, not the html

Comment: I'm new in MVC.  I like to ask if how am i going to pass the selected items to the controller. Should I put it in an array and then use it in the query?

Comment: Show the method your posting to - it should have parameter `(string[] software_type)`.

Comment: That's the thing I'd like to ask. I'm still confused on how to pass the array in the linq query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your POST method is

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create_Report(string[] software_type)
```

then `software_type` will contain an array of the selected values so you can use `.Contains()` to filter the query

```
var items = db.Software.Where(s => software_type.Contains(s.software_type))
```

Side note: remove those awful underscores from your properties and follow normal naming conventions (SoftwareType, SoftwareName, etc or simply Type, Name etc since they are already in a class named Software)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a collection to store you selected items and use model binding to map the selected items to this property.

```
//store checked Items
public IEnumerable<string> SelectedSoftware { get; set; }
//check box list items
public List<string> SoftwareList = new List<string>();

 foreach (var item in Model.SoftwareList )
    {
        <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedSoftware" value="@item">@item

    }
```

in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Create_Report(string[] SelectedSoftware)
    {
       //do action
    }
```

Comment: What would happen during the query?